# Highlight stroke of the Unbounded font family in Subtitle

Tags: html, css, svg

I can't stroke text in the Unbounded font family with transparent text color in Subtitle.
I have tried styling text using *text-shadow*, *stroke*, and *svg+stroke*.
As a result, I expected to get transparent text with a white stroke and no lines crossing.

If you choose a different font family (for example, **Open Sans**), then there are no line intersections and the text looks beautiful.

I want to get the result of font selection using stroke (as in Open Sans) on the **Unbounded** font family only.

Here's my code:
https://codepen.io/aptyyyp/pen/JjexrBQ

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #323232 4%, rgba(217, 217, 217, 0) 100%);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.main__img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.main__wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.main__wrap svg {
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.main__title {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
  font-family: "Unbounded", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 96px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 4.8px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.main__subtitle {
  font-family: "Unbounded", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.heading--stroke {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.heading--text-shadow {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: #fff 0px 0px 1px, #fff 0px 0px 1px, #fff 0px 0px 1px, #fff 0px 0px 1px, #fff 0px 0px 1px, #fff 0px 0px 1px;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Unbounded:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<main class="main">
  <div class="main__img">
    <img src="" alt="Image">
  </div>
  <div class="main__wrap">
    <h1 class="main__title">Example text Title</h1>
    <svg width="350" height="75" viewBox="0 0 350 75">
          <title>Example Text Subtitle SVG + Stroke</title>
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="350" height="75" style="fill: transparent" />
          <g style="overflow: hidden; text-anchor: middle; font-family: 'Unbounded', sans-serif; font-weight: 600; font-size: 48px; line-height: 60px; text-transform: capitalize; word-wrap: break-word;">
            <text x="175" y="55" style="fill: transparent; stroke: #fff; stroke-width: 1">
              Example text Subtitle (SVG + stroke)
            </text>
          </g>
        </svg>
    <div class="main__title heading--stroke">Example text Subtitle (stroke)</div>
    <div class="main__title heading--text-shadow">Example text Subtitle (text-shadow)</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOVerflow! Please take a look at the article on [How to Ask a Good Question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as it will help you out in the future.  Please include your code directly in the question instead of linking to it on another site.  Your question becomes much easier to answer when the code you want help with is actually in the question. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76823186/edit) and click the button in the toolbar that looks like `[<>]` to add a code snippet to your question.

Comment: You won't get what you want with that font. The font developers decided to draw intersecting lines as a way to make it a [variable font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_font). I would consider this a bug, but the developers might see it otherwise - you have to take it up with [them](https://github.com/googlefonts/unbounded#authors). The `text-shadow` works [as expected](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor/#text-shadow-property): _"Unlike `box-shadow`, text shadows are not clipped to the shadowed shape and may show through if the text is partially-transparent."_